# Как сделать перенос на новую строку Ionic Framework

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, ionic

В приложении текст находится на локальном Json файле, в самом файле уже указано где сделать переносы, они не работают при отображении в приложении, перенос текста пробовал в разных вариациях: \n, \n\r, \\n, так же пробовал html теги для переноса
[image: Ionic Json]

Сам Json:

```
"recipe":"In a small skillet over medium heat, melt butter. \nAdd chopped onions, garlic and tomato paste and sweat them for 5 minutes to soften and sweeten. Sprinkle in sugar and remove from heat. Cool in a bowl, 5 minutes. Add tomato paste mixture, Worcestershire, hot sauce to bowl and combine. Add chicken to the bowl then grill seasoning and combine the burgers well to evenly distribute the flavors and form 4 patties. Wash up.\n Heat 1 tablespoon extra-virgin olive oil, a turn of the pan, in a nonstick skillet over medium-high heat. Cook patties 6 minutes on each side.\nCombine the honey, lemon juice, and remaining extra-virgin olive oil in a bowl. Add relish, cabbage mix and sliced onions and season with salt and pepper. Toss the slaw to coat and reserve.\nServe burgers on bun bottoms topped with slaw and bun tops.",
```

Код страницы Ionic:

```css
page-detail {
    
}

h1{

}

.card-detail-page {
    
    ion-card {
        //position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
        width: 100%;
        //right: 8pt;
              
    }

    h1 {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 150%;
        font-weight: normal;
        padding-bottom: 2rem;
    }

    h2 {
        //padding: 2rem;
        //text-align: left;
        font-size: 120%;
        font-weight: normal;
        
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: center;

        //border-bottom: 2px solid mediumseagreen;
        //padding-bottom: 1rem;
    }

    h2:before,
    h2:after {
     content: '';
     display: inline-block;
     width: 100%;
     height: 1px;
     background: #14D338;
     z-index: -1;
     position: relative;
     vertical-align: middle;
    }

    h2:before {
        right: 15px;
        margin: 0 0 0 -100%;
       }
    h2:after {
        left: 15px;
        margin: 0 -100% 0 0;
       }

    .recipe {
        text-align: justify;
        padding: 2rem;
    }

    
    

    /*.card-title {
        position: absolute;
        top: 88%;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        width: 100%;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #fff;
        background: rgba(5 , 5, 5, 0.28);
        
    }*/

    
}
```

```html
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>{{person.title}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content class="card-detail-page">
 
    <ion-card>
        <img src={{person.picture}}/>
    </ion-card>
    
      <h1>{{person.title}}</h1>
      
      <h2>Ingredients</h2>

      <div class="recipe">
          {{person.ingredients}}        
      </div>

      <h2>Recipe</h2>
      <div class="recipe">{{person.recipe}}</div>
       
  
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Подстановка текста происходит через Element.innerHTML = "text"?

Comment: в общем должно работать, либо <br>, либо \r\n c css свойством white-space: pre;